# access elements of a void *?

Tags: c++

I have a void pointer and want to access elements from it. How could I transform a void * into an unsigned byte pointer so I can access its elements (which I know are actually unsigned bytes).
Thanks

Using C++

Comment: In C or C++?  They are totally different languages, especially with regard to casting.

Comment: The mechanism is different, but the end result is basically the same in both languages.

Comment: ((unsigned char *)ptr)[i] will work fine in both languages.

Comment: @user168715: It will work, but it is generally considered a better choice to use the cast operators in C++ to make the intended type of cast explicit.

Comment: Other than the warm feeling that some people get from following dogma, a reinterpret case between two pointer types is no better than the equivalent c-cast.

Comment: ... it is actually not equivalent to the C-style cast at all. An equivalent cast would be `static_cast`.

Comment: @Alan: While the C++-style cast doesn't change the results, it accomplishes three things: 1) a `reinterpret_cast<int*>` stands out in the code a lot more than `(int*)`, which is good.  You want people looking and making sure you're doing the right thing there.  2) It's a lot easier to search for C++-style casts.  3) What type of cast is at work here? `int* myPtr = (int*)data;`  Is it a const cast?  A reinterpret cast?  A static cast?  More importantly, what did the programmer think it was doing?  C++-style casts convey that information, at the cost of little extra effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast it to the appropriate type you are using for an "unsigned byte".  Once it's casted appropriately, you can access it as if it is an array (access elements).

```
unsigned char* bytePointer = static_cast<unsigned char*>(originalVoidPointer);
unsigned char elementFive = bytePointer[5];
```

Comment: There is no type named "byte" in C.

Comment: Yes, I am surprised at the two upvotes considering there is no such thing as a 'byte' type in C++.

Comment: Th OP said they were "unsigned bytes".  Presumably, (s)he has a `typedef char byte;` defined.

Comment: @Fred: That was my assumption when I wrote this.  Clarified my answer.

Comment: @Charles, @aviraldg, and @Ed: I was assuming, given the OP's wording, that there was a byte typedef in place.  If not, he could of course use unsigned char.

Comment: @Fred Larson: Seems like a strange assumption to me considering that C++ has a native type for unsigned bytes called `unsigned char`. And how does `typedef char byte;` magically create an `unsigned byte` type?

Comment: If he had cast it to Foo no one would question it. But by using the word byte he's committed some kind of error. Interesting.....

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something painfully obvious but I just can't see any way to make `unsigned byte` actual refer to a type or any way to make the syntax `reinterpret_cast<unsigned byte>(originalVoidPointer)` compile. `typedef char byte;` doesn't magically make `unsigned byte` valid a type and a typedef'ed identifier must be one word so you can't `typedef unsigned char unsigned byte`.

Comment: OK, you could do `#define byte char` but that's just evil.

Comment: I've removed my misplaced upvote, both for `unsigned byte` and for that `reinterpret_cast` (`static_cast` would be correct).

Comment: @jmucchiello: Read Charles' answer. Additionally, the reasoning is that Java has the byte type.

Comment: @avakar & @Charles: Better?  I just simplified it to ignore the OP's "byte" reference.  There should be little complaints here.

Answer (score 6):

```
// Assuming you have a void* declared:
void* p;

// and it's initialized to point to a valid object (array of bytes)
// somewhere here...

// ...

// You can convert it to a pointer to unsigned char:
unsigned char* bytes = static_cast<unsigned char*>(p);

// ... and access the bytes using []
unsigned char x = bytes[0];
```

Of course the byte offset you use must be within the size of the object that the `void*` actually points to.

Answer (score 4):

```
index[reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(voidPointer)]
```

Comment: Because at the time I answered, the question was still tagged C.

Comment: By the way, I'd avoid that syntax, it's widely known on SO because it's been pointed out several times for general enjoyment, but the average programmer would say that's it's not correct C/C++.

Comment: -1, why `reinterpret_cast` with implementation defined results instead of a simple and valid `static_cast`?

Comment: No, I really meant why the cast for C. Not that the comment is relevant to the question any more.

Comment: Without the cast, both in C and in C++, the compiler wouldn't know how to do the pointer arithmetic, since void elements don't have a definite size.

Comment: @Matteo: You can convert a `void*` to an `unsigned char*` perfectly well without a case and the original form of this answer didn't have as much context as the C++ only version now does, so it wasn't clear how the suggested cast syntax was to be used.

Comment: That cast in C is done implicitly if you are assigning a void pointer to another pointer type, but in this suggestion there's no assignment, and the compiler, without the cast, wouldn't have any clue that it has to interpret the void pointer as a pointer to unsigned char.

Comment: @Matteo: As I said, the original form of this answer lacked enough context so it wasn't clear how the suggested cast syntax was to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You typecast. If its is C, then you should use something like:

```
((unsigned char *) void_ptr)[index];
```

If its C++, then you shouldn't be using void pointers at all.

Comment: I've run into plenty of external libraries (particularly GUI-related) whose APIs require the use of void pointers. 'twould be a shame to never use them in C++ projects.

Comment: If it ain't broken, don't fix it.

Comment: ... implying that "such" libraries should use pointers to the base type instead.

Comment: void pointers still have plenty of uses in C++, especially when performing low level code.

Comment: I usually write pure C code then, and link against it (with use of extern "C"). But yes, there are *valid* uses of void pointers in C++ code...